# Does extending html pages to other pages through Django or Flask increase load times?

Tags: html, django, performance

Such as using `{% extends 'base.html' %}`.

Inside of an `index.html` file or any other.

I would think so because I would assume multiple requests would be being made to the server. Then again I'm not completely sure how Django operates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can safely ignore the time "extends" take. I've found that a lot of "includes" can take a long time and lot of resources, according to debug-toolbar's template timer, if you use them inside loops. But not using extends would be a suicide and the time they take can be ignored.